# Dynamically add browser name into page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small script that detects the userAgent and basically writes a small 'hello' message with the browser the user is using. I'm using it for a small demo i'll be showing to people, I know feature detection is better so don't worry. It's mainly to demo the script.

But basically, I was wondering if there is any better way to write this:

http://jsfiddle.net/m5cVf/

I need to show a quick fun little message, but instead of doing loads of 'if' statements for each browser, I want to put them in array and add the browser name into the function if the current browser is true, rather than calling `doAlert();` multiple times.

Something like:

```
var browsers = chrome,safari,mozilla;
```

then if the browser in use is 'true' this would get added into the function instead of manually adding them inside each 'if' statement. Thanks and much appreciated!

Comment: ... or an list of objects with "search" and "answer" properties, and a loop to iterate through it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could store the browser types in an array, loop through them, and test them against the found user agent. Like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/m5cVf/5/

```
var browsers = [{"testWith": "chrome", "displayName": "Google Chrome"},
                {"testWith": "safari", "displayName": "Apple Safari"},
                {"testWith": "mozilla", "displayName": "Mozilla Browser"}];

function showBrowserName(browser) {
    $('.user').text(browser);
}

$(function () {
    var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();

    for (var i = 0; i < browsers.length; i++) {
        var cur = browsers[i];
        if (userAgent.indexOf(cur.testWith) > -1) {
            showBrowserName(cur.displayName);
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @ToddM. No problem! I just updated with a newer version. There are many possibilities for what you could do with this. I know it's just for testing, but I'm not sure "chrome", "safari", and "mozilla" are the best strings to use to test, just saying. You could always make the "testWith" attribute be a list of possible strings that would be used to represent it in a User Agent and check each.

Comment: Ian, thanks for taking the time to do this. Is there anything better you'd recommend running the test against? I know some UA strings have multiple browser declarations inside - but so far seems to work perfectly.

Comment: @ToddM. Seriously no problem. Well, I would just take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to do this:
http://jsfiddle.net/m5cVf/6/

```
function browser(){
    var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    var browsers = ['chrome', 'safari', 'mozilla'];
    for(n in browsers) {
        if(userAgent.indexOf(browsers[n]) > -1){
            browserName = browsers[n];
            doAlert();
            return;
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice, thanks very much for helping out. Still a great answer, but Ian posted first so had to give the green tick to him! :-)